Arrangements of fixed k-polyplets in a $n\times n$ matrix
Recently, I asked a question about the number of arrangements of $k$ elements inside a $n\times n$ matrix with certain restrictions. The one I´m actually interested in for this question is in its 2. case, but with $k$ elements instead of only $4$.
To find a general formula as a function of $n$ and $k$, I can use the A006770 sequence that counts all the fixed polyplets formed with $k$ elements, and then for each type of fixed k-polyplet count all its arrangements inside the matrix, which is easy since it can only be translated, not rotated, reflected, or any other transformation.
However, there are 2 problems with this approach:

Is there a general formula for the A006770 sequence as a function of the number of elements forming the cluster? (We can denote it as $p(k)$)

If it exists, it would only provide the number of fixed polyplets, but each one can have a size of $(1,k),(2,k),(3,k),\cdots,(k,k)$. That is, for each polyplet, if we want to calculate in how many distinct ways we can place it into the matrix (arrangements), we would need to know its exact size $(s_x,s_y)$, so there would be $(n-s_x)\cdot (n-s_y)$ possible arrangements. The problem is that the exact size is apparently unknown for each one, since there isn´t a clear relation about how many of the total $p(k)$ polyplets of $k$ elements have a size of $(1,k)$, $(2,k)$, or its corresponding one. So my question is, is there any property that can simplify the counting so that it isn´t necessary to account for how many of the $p(k)$ polyplets have a determined size $(s_x,s_y)$?


Finally, I managed to calculate the arrangements formula $a(n,k)$ for certain values of $k$:
$a(n,1)=n^2$
$a(n,2)=4 n^2-6 n+2$
$a(n,3)=20 n^2-56 n+36$
$a(n,4)=110 n^2+4 n-29$
$a(n,5)=638 n^2+612 n-94$
Somehow, $a(n,4)$ only works for $n>2$ and $a(n,5)$ only works for $n>3$, you can see more on this question.
